# js bind input name to parent index

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding

Is it possible to bind input element name to its parent index (div) so whenever div index changes input name is changed automatically? Something like this:

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="parent.index"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess thats what you need:

```
<div onchange = "this.children[0].name=this.parentNode.indexOf(this)">
<input type="text" />
</div>
```